# Why is there so much fear surrounding sea buckthorn?

Tags: berries

Talking to a few people I've heard they're afraid of the plant being planted. Why is that?

One reason I heard was because it's related to the russian olive.

Comment: Thorns, vigourous growth and hard to get rid of? Plus pretty strong roots that can even lift pavers? In short, the same that goes for blackberries/brambles and many invasive plants and creepers.

Comment: Listed as 'spread indefinite' might also be a factor

Comment: Fear is when you don't know what will happen.  Sea buckthorn has a place but it's far far away from residential gardens and commercial plantings due to the notes listed above by the essential Stephie and Bamboo

Comment: @Stephie so it's invasive, when they say it isn't on the state list of invasive plants?

Comment: Plants usually only make it on a restricted list when the are introduced and become a problem. It's more a reactive list than proactive. In Minnesota it is on the restricted invasive list. http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/invasives/terrestrialplants/woody/buckthorn/index.html Be a good gardner and neighbor and do not plant known invasives whether they are on the list or not.

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY We are talking about *sea* buckthorn (Hippophae rhamnoides), not buckthorn (Rhamnus cathartica), but yes, the same prnciples apply.

Comment: this article indicates that sea buckthorn is an up and coming invasive in Alberta http://www.ou.edu/cas/botany-micro/ben/ben345.html

Comment: @Stephie my bad. I see invasives and I'm eager to chime in. I stand by everything else I said in the comment besides the bad link.

Comment: For any readers in Northern Europe, where this is a native plant, I should add that there is no need to fear this plant there. It is a wonderful plant, attractive, makes excellent windbreaks and hedges, good for stabilizing banks. The fruit is highly nutritious (if a little messy to collect) and believed to be protective against cardiovascular disease. Even if you don't eat it yiurself, the birds will love you for it.

Comment: @dww I have three in my garden and I picked them on purpose. No need to "fear" it, but anyone who plants it *should be aware of its characteristics* and prepared to manage them. There are many plants where the same rule applies, our neighbour had a golden elm that kept popping up in our yard and the rosa rugosa hedge our previous owner of our house planted still isn't totally gone two years after we dug it up.